# Appropriate way to pass a dataset to Java from Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, cursor

I need to pass datasets from Oracle to Java through JDBC.

How is it better to organize it so that everything works well and it would be convenient both for Java developers and PL/SQL developers to maintain the code in case of changing, for example, table column types?

I see such variants:

1. Pass the **sys_refcursor** via stored procedure, and in Java expect that there will be certain fields with a certain type of data.
2. Pass a **strong ref cursor** and in Java do the same, that in item 1, but in the PL/SQL package there is a type description.
3. Pass **SQL "table of" type, described at the schema level**. If I understand correctly, in Java apparently it can somehow be applied to the object. The problem is that in these types it is impossible to do fields with the column type - Column_Name%TYPE.
4. Conduct in the **PL/SQL package "table of object / record" type**, and using **JPublisher** to work with it - JPublisher apparently converts it into a SQL type. It is not entirely clear for me how this is implemented, and what needs to be done for the same case when the data type of the column changes.
5. Using the **pipelined function** instead of the cursor (does this even make sense for such a task?).

What to choose? Or maybe something else, not from these points?

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: if want to have convenient and generic way for DB and java developer use `sys_refcursor`.  In jdbc handling of `sys_refcursor` is exactly the same like for normal query. `sys_refcursor = ResultSet`.

Comment: The answer is, *it depends*. None of these options is right for every circumstance. If there was one which was always the best solution it would be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i've understood your queston right, but i think you confused.

The variants, which you discribed is way to execute Java package on server side (for example, when you have database with application servers and want execute java package on it with data of database).

But if you thinking about JDBC then i guess that you want to make some java-app which could work with database. So that you don't have to user some `sys_refcursor` of subtupes like `table of object / record`. The JDBC provides capabilities to work with datasets using simple SQL. You should just connect to database as user (via JDBC) and execute sql query. After that you can get any data from result set.
Examples:
[Connection example via JDBC](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/)
[Execute select after connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

So the answer for your question depends on yours goals.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But the user under which the Java server connects will not have rights to select either from the tables or from the views

Comment: @archjkee, just give the user's `GRANT` in DB.  You couldn't work with subtypes without grants too.

Comment: Our DB architect said that we will NOT give grants on any schema objects, except the grant execute on packages (maybe plus grants on types, procedures)

Comment: but you have wrote that you wanted to use subtypes like **sys_refcursors**, which based on select to tables. You have to have grants to execute select, for example. I meant this detail.

    
So as i told, the answer for your question depends on yours goals.

Comment: We have <dev_schema>, that have grants to select from tables. And we have <schema_for_java_connection>, that have only grants to execute packages from the <dev_schema>.